# Как записать число с пробелами между его цифрами?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как записать число с пробелами между его цифрами?
Например:
Входные данные:
123456789
Выходные данные:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Python 3.7.0

Comment: `print(*str(123456789))`

Answer (score 6):

```py
print(" ".join(str(123456789)))
```

- `str(123456789)` возвращает строковое представление числа;
- `" ".join` объединяет все элементы итерируемого объекта (в данном случае цифры) с пробелом в качестве разделителя, возвращает строку.

Comment: @insolor 3, 4, 5 - цифры. 855 - число :)

Comment: Да, точно, ошибся